# What are parents with a living child called, compared to "Shidu" parents (parents who have lost their only child)?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

The parents who have lost their only child are known as *Shidu* parents (失独父母) in China, I don't think ‘normal parents’ is a good phrase, do you have any suggestions? I want to use this phrase in a research article.

Comment: Reading the question as it is, it looks like she's looking for a term for parents that currently have children?  Common things we say to suggest that a person is in a current parenting role might be "Parents with young children" or "Parents of high school students" or alternatively, "parents of grown children"  (which suggests they're not in the active parenting role).  If you instead meant the opposite perhaps: "Parents who have lost their children" would be a parallel way of saying things the same way.

Comment: “Parents with living children” is probably your best bet. There isn't a term for this in English, just like there isn't one for 失独 either.

Comment: Is there a Chinese term for the word you're after? If you post the Chinese term, perhaps we could use a literal translation to figure out an idiomatic expression in English.

Comment: @Lawrence not really, maybe "an intact family"? 健全的家庭

Comment: In that case, I second Janus Bahs Jacquet's suggestion to use your phrase, "parents with living children / a living child".

Comment: Is a parent still a parent, by definition, if they no longer have children?

Comment: @Hank When they're attending the funeral, how would you describe their relationship to the deceased child?

Comment: @Barmar  If I knew, I wouldn't have made my comment. I probably would call them the parents of the deceased, but that doesn't make it correct. My opinion is that they are still parents. But, the definition of the word "parent" may disagree with me.

Comment: @Hank Sorry, I thought you meant it as a rhetorical question, implying that you don't think they are. Or maybe something like the language philosophy question about whether the phrase "present King of France" makes sense.

Comment: @Barmar No worries. I like to take opinions out sometimes and just look at pure definitions; regardless of whether it would be practiced or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent in English.

There is a proposed equivalent of *Shidu*: *vilomah*.

> A parent whose child has died is a vilomah.

The quote is from an opinion paper at [Duke](https://today.duke.edu/2009/05/holloway_oped.html), the sentiment of which can be confirmed by a web search as having some adoption is specialized communities.

Comment: You're answering the opposite question since it is looking for a word for "parents with a **living** child"

Comment: The first sentence is a terse answer to the question. Sometimes “no” is the answer.